# Manually install a package (QSTK) into Canopy Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, pip, canopy

I really like the Canopy environment but unfortunately the package I want to use, QSTK, is not pre-installed and it is not available in its package manager.

Can I use pip to install QSTK for this environment? Or am too naive and about to crash my computer unknowingly?

I found all of the site-packages located in:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages>

Answer (score 1):

Installed QSTK using pip while in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages> in the command prompt!

Comment: The key is not what is your current directory but what is your default python. See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line (tl;dr - do it from a Canopy Command Prompt that you can open from the Canopy Tools menu).